# How can I set a WPF control's color to a system color programmatically, so that it updates on color scheme changes?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I do this in WPF's code-behind?

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. I'm still learning WPF and I couldn't figure out how to do this in XAML, but your question shows exactly how to do it. I used this instead:

<Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW you don't need to define the DynamicResource, you can access the static brush directly: Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}"

Comment: I revise my earlier comment: You do need to specify a DynamicResource if you think your users will change the system theme while you application is running. If you just use the {x:Static ... } and the theme changes, your application colors won't change to match. Also DynamicResource is necessary when using a Style's Setter, e.g. <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just found an ugly solution:

```
grid1.SetResourceReference(
    Control.BackgroundProperty,
    SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey);
```

I hope someone will post a better one (I'd like to see something like grid1.Background = BackgroundBrush, because the syntax of SetResourceReference is a step backwards from Windows Forms).

Comment: I don't think this is ugly. Looks pretty normal if you want to do it in code behind.

Answer (score 9):

This must have been added to a later version of WPF since this was originally posted because your original code works fine for me (I'm using WPF 4.5)

`<Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey}}"/>`

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question. OP knows that the XAML code works. He is looking for the equivalent code-behind, i.e. C# code.

Answer (score 6):

Extension methods might help:

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
    // usage xPanel.SetBackground(SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey);
    public static void SetBackground(this Panel panel, ResourceKey key)
    {
        panel.SetResourceReference(Panel.BackgroundProperty, key);
    }

    // usage xControl.SetBackground(SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey);
    public static void SetBackground(this Control control, ResourceKey key)
    {
        control.SetResourceReference(Control.BackgroundProperty, key);
    }
}
```

Comment: this can be changed to the following, because all of thies are of type FrameworkElement:<br/>    `public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
   {
      // usage xControl.SetBackground(SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey);
      public static void SetBackground(this FrameworkElement control, ResourceKey key)
      {
         control.SetResourceReference(Control.BackgroundProperty, key);
      }
   }`

Answer (score 3):

.NET Framework Supported in: 3.0

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.highlightbrush(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en_us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.highlightbrushkey(v=vs.85).aspx

```
this.background=SystemColors.HighlightBrush;
```

Comment: Note that this won't get updated when the System Color changes like when the user switches to Hi-Contrast mode unless you listen for change events and reset it manually.

Comment: ```SystemColors.GrayTextBrush``` is what I was looking for