# Get Aero Window Colour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, aero

I've made a pretty slick Windows 8-ish interface using WPF. It already turns out way better than I could wish for, but I was wondering the following:

Is it somehow possible to retrieve the current window colour set by the user? You know, you can set the Aero colour when you right-click the desktop... My plan is to use that colour for a couple of canvas elements on my GUI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628483/how-can-i-set-a-wpf-controls-color-to-a-system-color-programatically-so-that-i

Comment: The proper way is to pinvoke DwmGetColorizationColor()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the ColorizationColor registry key for this.

I've even went a step further and created a method to get the hexadecimal colour value, hope this helps you:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    int argbColor = (int)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM","ColorizationColor", null);
    var color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(argbColor);
    string hexadecimalColor = ConverterToHex(color);
}


private static String ConverterToHex(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    return String.Format("#{0}{1}{2}", c.R.ToString("X2"), c.G.ToString("X2"), c.B.ToString("X2"));
}
```

Comment: I'm using your code instead, since I need the color in the code behind. I figured I'd better put it all together to maintain readability.

Comment: My answer will also change the color when the Aero color in fact changes (which happens often in Windows 8 with automatic coloring enabled).

Comment: How can I tell if this value changed with binding to SystemColors.WindowColorKey

Answer (score 5):

The [SystemColours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class exists for this very purpose.  You can bind directly to it like so

```
"{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"
```

Comment: So very simple! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the correct colour using the following code:
*Little sidenote: It has a small correction in it to ignore the alpha bit of the hex number, so I get the full color rather than the less saturated one.*

```
string colorizationValue = string.Format("{0:x}", Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM", "ColorizationColor", "00000000"));
StringBuilder bl = new StringBuilder(colorizationValue);
bl[0] = 'd';
bl[1] = '9';
colorizationValue = bl.ToString();

BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
Brush brush = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#" + colorizationValue);
cvs_barColor.Background = brush;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an open-source library for this [here](https://github.com/ffMathy/aerocolor-wpf) which is also available on NuGet.

`install-package aerocolor-wpf.AeroColor`

After installing the package, you can refer to a `DynamicResource` called `AeroColor` and `AeroBrush` depending on what you need.

There's some setup code that's needed too, but it isn't much. Just put something in your `Loaded` event handler of the window, as seen below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AeroResourceInitializer.Initialize();
    }
}
```

The neat thing about this library is that it installs a hook as well, which updates those resources as the actual Aero color changes in the system too. This means you don't have to handle that either, and if you use a `DynamicResource` to point to the color in your XAML instead of a `StaticResource`, WPF will automatically update the color in your UI as well.

Looks very cool when Windows 8 changes the Aero color transitionally and your color follows.