# How to get Active Caption background color base on user choice?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, caption

I'm making a custom border window, but still want to use the caption background color that user choose in Desktop -> Personalize -> Color.
I expect I can get this color by `SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrush` or `SystemParameters. WindowGlassBrush`, but it is others color.
How can I get that color? Thank.

Comment: Is that what you want: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085959/get-aero-window-colour)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Color.FromArgb(153,180,209);

Comment: what if **user's choice** is not that color?

Comment: This is part of the answer: the current answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085959/get-aero-window-colour